# How do I perform bonus actions?

Tags: flatout-ultimate-carnage

In FlatOut: Ultimate Carnage, during a race you may earn some additional money by performing some bonus actions (Slam, Power Hit, Fastest lap - although this one is pretty obvious !, Blast Out...). At the end of the race, there is a recap of all of them.

The way to perform them seem to be explained in the loading screens, but it seems that my computer is too fast to load, and I never could read any of the tips displayed there.

What should I do to obtain those bonuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slam and Power Hit refer to the speeds at which you crash into an opponent (with Slam being at lower speeds and Power Hit being it higher, more damaging speeds). You get the Blast Out bonus when you literally make an opponent leave the drivers seat (via the windscreen).